# TypeError: string indices must be integers in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a dataFrame with 1 column of 'JSON' or dictionary type data in strings. To convert it into Python Dictionary, I came up with following code from Stackoverflow

```py
class Iden():
  def __getitem__(name, index):
    return index

df['genres'].map(lambda a: eval(str(a), {}, Iden()))
```

which converts it into dictionary, which I confirmed using following code,

```py
df['genres'].map(lambda a: eval(str(a), {}, Iden())).map(lambda a: type(a[0]))
```

and my output was

```
0       <class 'dict'>
1       <class 'dict'>
2       <class 'dict'>
3       <class 'dict'>
4       <class 'dict'>
             ...
```

Now, single variable of `genres` is as follows

```
"[{'id': 35, 'name': 'Comedy'}]"
```

I want to extract the `name` from this and my code is

```py
df['genres'].map(lambda a: eval(str(a), {}, Iden())).map(lambda a: a[0]['name'])
```

but it is giving error

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-109-3da37181d7d9> in <module>
----> 1 df['genres'].map(lambda a: eval(str(a), {}, Iden())).map(lambda a: a[0]['name'])

C:\Anaconda\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in map(self, arg, na_action)
   3628         dtype: object
   3629         """
-> 3630         new_values = super()._map_values(arg, na_action=na_action)
   3631         return self._constructor(new_values, index=self.index).__finalize__(self)
   3632 

C:\Anaconda\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\base.py in _map_values(self, mapper, na_action)
   1143 
   1144         # mapper is a function
-> 1145         new_values = map_f(values, mapper)
   1146 
   1147         return new_values

pandas\_libs\lib.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer()

<ipython-input-109-3da37181d7d9> in <lambda>(a)
----> 1 df['genres'].map(lambda a: eval(str(a), {}, Iden())).map(lambda a: a[0]['name'])

TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

First 5 rows of `genres` is

```
0                       [{'id': 35, 'name': 'Comedy'}]
1    [{'id': 35, 'name': 'Comedy'}, {'id': 18, 'nam...
2                        [{'id': 18, 'name': 'Drama'}]
3    [{'id': 53, 'name': 'Thriller'}, {'id': 18, 'n...
4    [{'id': 28, 'name': 'Action'}, {'id': 53, 'nam...
```

What can be potential reason and potential fix for this error?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use JSON:

```
import json
s = "[{'id': 35, 'name': 'Comedy'}]"
s = s.replace("'", '"')
l = json.loads(s)

l[0]["name"] # -> 'Comedy'
```

So you would do something like:

```
df["genres"].apply(lambda s: json.loads(s.replace("'", '"'))[0]["name"])
```

Comment: Yes I am aware, I edited my reply, I just pointed out how he can solve his problem

Comment: About the no key problem, this is another problem

Answer (score 0):

Use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/ast.html) for convert jsons to dictionaries and then select first list by indexing with `str[0]` and first `name` by [`Series.str.get`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get.html), it return missing values if no first list or no `name` key in dictionary:

```
import ast
    
df['genres'].map(ast.literal_eval).str[0].str.get('name')
```